# how to modify an apk file without changing its signature?

Tags: android, apk

I wanna at least remove some permissions, and this is also an system app. İ have to install the modified apk on the already installed system app. Is there a way, or is that impossible?

Answer (score 0):

It should be impossible - everything else is a bug

Comment: Can you explain why it's impossible?

Comment: Because otherwise it would be an security-flaw